# How can I use regex to remove scripts from html tag

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and copy-pasted from an old site a bunch of script tags and now it's loading them to my pages which causes excessive page-load times.

So I want to remove the scripts, but there are a lot of pages and those scripts are inserted into custom fields mixed with the actual text.

I have this search-and -eplace plugin which uses regex but I'm not sure how I can use regex to remove them.

Here's an xample:

```html
<!-- Jquery scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tipTip.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gothanmedium_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gothanbold_700.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gothanbook_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End Jquery scripts -->
```

I was wondering if I can start the expression from the comment tag `<!-- Jquery scripts -->` and end with `<!-- End Jquery scripts -->` so to remove all of them altogether.

Comment: What plugin (or what regex flavor does it use)? What have you tried?

Comment: You should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts()` to include JS files on your site. You shouldn't be using JavaScript to remove `<script>` tags like this.

Comment: @Mariano - I'm using HTML Cleanup and it ask to use this. http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: @mevius - I know that. Like I said, I copied and pasted texts from an old badly coded static site. When I copied texts, it copied those scripts (which I don't know why is there) in my WP editor too. Now I want it all removed. Can't find any other solutions other than manually removing it which is so much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regex.

```
|(<!-- Jquery scripts -->[\s\S]+<!-- End Jquery scripts -->)|gim
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/fW4iU5/2)

Comment: I wouldn't have any idea how to do this. Thanks so much!